# HEVC with alpha showing all frames at the same time

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-graphics, scenekit, core-video

I'm making a video with transparent background using HEVC with alpha, based on a bunch of `NSImage`s, a `CVPixelBuffer` pool and `AVAssetWriter`. The `NSImage`s are rendered by an `SCNRenderer`'s `[snapshot][1]` method.

To turn the `NSImage`s into `CVPixelbuffer`s so I can append them to the pool, I first get a new pixel buffer from the pool, then use this code

```swift
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        
        guard let context = CGContext(
            data: pixelData,
            width: Int(image.size.width),
            height: Int(image.size.height),
            bitsPerComponent: 8, 
            bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer),
            space: colorSpace,
            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue
        )
        else { return  }
        
        let graphicsContext = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: context, flipped: false)
        
        NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
        NSGraphicsContext.current = graphicsContext
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
        NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()
        
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
```

In the exported movie, the colors look good, and the transparency kicks in fine.

But all the frames are added on top of each other, as in the example below.

SIDE NOTE: The weird thing is that if I obtain the pixel buffer with Metal (using the SCNRenderer's `render` method), but leave everything else as is, it works fine. That's why I'm suspecting that it might be my `CGContext` that is acting up. Why don't I just use Metal, then? Would love to, but [I can't get antialiasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64958392/antialiasing-a-scenekit-rendering-with-metal).

[image]

Comment: how is `SCNRenderer` used? Is the Metal texture correctly cleared? (the `MTLRenderPassDescriptor`'s `colorAttachments[0].loadAction` should be `MTLLoadActionClear`)

Comment: It works when I use Metal. So I'm wondering if there's something similar I can do with NSImage/CVPixelBuffer—Metal method: I call the SCNRenderer's `render` and pass in a commandBuffer—NSImage method: I call the SCNRenderer's `snapshot` and convert the resulting image to a `CVPixelBuffer`

Comment: It's hard to grasp the issue and where it might fail without the entire code but sticking to Metal is a good idea. I posted an answer for your other issue too.

Comment: You made my day. Accepted your answer there.